# Filter rows that meet two differential conditions

Tags: r, variables, filter, conditional-statements

I'm looking for elegant code which filter rows that meet two  conditions in a differential way, to a new df:

```
filter (birth_year==1987 & graduation_year==2005)
       (birth_year==1990 & graduation_year==2008)
       (birth_year==1993 & graduation_year==2011)
       (birth_year==1998 & graduation_year==2016)
#this is not a code
```

Here is my df:

```
birth_year <- c(1987,1987,1987,1990,1990,1990,1993,1993,1998,1998)
graduation_year <- c(2005,2005,2006,2008,2007,2008,2011,2012,2017,2016)
grade<-c(56,101,85,120,75,96,85,68,91,105)

df <- data.frame(birth_year, graduation_year, grade)

> df
   birth_year graduation_year grade
1        1987            2005    56
2        1987            2005   101
3        1987            2006    85
4        1990            2008   120
5        1990            2007    75
6        1990            2008    96
7        1993            2011    85
8        1993            2012    68
9        1998            2017    91
10       1998            2016   105
```

the result/the new df  should be:

```
   birth_year graduation_year grade
1        1987            2005    56
2        1987            2005   101
3        1990            2008   120
4        1990            2008    96
5        1993            2011    85
6        1998            2016   105
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%in%` operator

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <- df %<%
  filter(birth_year %in% c(1987, 1990, 1993, 1998),
         graduation_year  %in% c(2005, 2008, 2011, 2016)
         )
```

Comment: hey you deleted the answer https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69995989/revisions Your answer is correct. Just do abit of tweeking eg `df1 %>%
  group_by(block = gl(nrow(.), 3, nrow(.)))%>%
  summarise(count = sum(x>3.2))` or even `group_by(block =  seq(0, n()) %/% 3 + 1)` or even ...

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case I think you could do it like this:

```
filter(graduation_year - birth_year == 18)
```

Another idea is creading a reference dataframe with your conditions like this:

```
birth_year <- c(1987, 1990, 1993, 1998)
graduation_year <- c(2005, 2008, 2011, 2016)

conditions <- data.frame(birth_year, graduation_year)
```

And then applying `inner_join`:

```
df %>% inner_join(conditions)

Joining, by = c("birth_year", "graduation_year")
  birth_year graduation_year grade
1       1987            2005    56
2       1987            2005   101
3       1990            2008   120
4       1990            2008    96
5       1993            2011    85
6       1998            2016   105
```

Comment: it is very easy :) but is there a generic way? I mean that the condition ==18 doesn't always exist

Answer (score 0):

You can simply separate your conditions with `|` so that you keep all of the records that meet either of them.

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <- df %>% filter(birth_year==1987 & graduation_year==2005 | 
       birth_year==1990 & graduation_year==2008 |
       birth_year==1993 & graduation_year==2011 | 
       birth_year==1998 & graduation_year==2016)
```